# How to equalize no of records in two lists for calculation in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an equation, for example, say `p1+p2`. I am calculating this equation using two lists.

```
List<P1> p_one and List<P2> p_two;
```

These two lists are based on time related data.
So in a day List p1 contains 200- 300 records and List p2 contains 100-200 records.
These tow list may contain the same DateTime data or nearly equal data or entirely different data.
For example

```
List<P1> p_one = new List<P1>() { 
            new P1(){ Value=1, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:01:00"},
            new P1(){ Value=2, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:03:00"},
            new P1(){ Value=3, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:05:00"},
            new P1(){ Value=1, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:06:00"},
            new P1(){ Value=3, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:08:00"},
            new P1(){ Value=5, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:11:00"},
            new P1(){ Value=6, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:14:25"},
            new P1(){ Value=4, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:15:00"},
        };
List<P2> p_two = new List<P2>() { 
            new P2(){ Value=1, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:01:00"},
            new P2(){ Value=8, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:03:50"},
            new P2(){ Value=3, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:04:30"},
            new P2(){ Value=1, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:06:15"},
            new P2(){ Value=3, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:08:00"},
            new P2(){ Value=3, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:10:26"},
            new P2(){ Value=6, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:14:00"},
            new P2(){ Value=7, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:15:10"},
            new P2(){ Value=9, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:16:10"},
            new P2(){ Value=7, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:17:10"},
        };
```

List `p_one` has 8 records and p_two has 10 records.

So my problem is on iterating through a loop basis, I want to calculate the above equation if the time is equal or nearly equal for both lists (for example `p_one`'s last record which has time  "2018-09-18 10:15:00" and second list has a nearly equal time "2018-09-18 10:15:10").If `p_one`'s time is 10:14:45 then equalize it with `p_two`'s time record 10:15:10 and if `p_one`'s time is 10:14:25 then equalize it with `p_two`'s time record 10:14:00. If dateTime dates are not equal or not nearly equal then neglect that records.

**UPDATE**

My criteria are 30 sec. Which mean below 30 sec roundoff time to lower minute and above 30 sec roundoff to the upper minute
The expecting result is a list.

```
List<RESULTSET> resultList = new List<RESULTSET>() { 
        new RESULTSET(){ Value=2, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:01:00"},
        new RESULTSET(){ Value=10, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:04:00"},
        new RESULTSET(){ Value=6, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:05:00"},
        new RESULTSET(){ Value=2, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:06:00"},
        new RESULTSET(){ Value=6, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:08:00"},
        new RESULTSET(){ Value=5, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:11:00"},
        new RESULTSET(){ Value=12, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:14:00"},
        new RESULTSET(){ Value=11, DateTime="2018-09-18 10:15:00"},
    };
```

the first result is adding first results with same time.Second result is sum of value = 3 , date = 2018-09-18 10:05:00 from p_one and Value=3, date=2018-09-18 10:04:30. So result is 6 and so on. So in the output list maximum records will be 8(for given example).

Comment: It is just an example, I didn't considering the data type here.

Comment: What do you mean by equalize (keep at only one place, merge entries or what else ?) and what is your criteria for equal (difference of 10 sec, 20 seconds, etc) ?

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: Can't you provide real data and your class? For example `DateTime` should be a `DateTime` and not a `String`. Providing pseudo code is rarely a good idea

Comment: The original result set is very large I just used two fields to understand it. DateTime is type datetime

Comment: What means _"equalize"_ at all? What is your desired result? I'm afraid your question isn't very clear, although i understand that you want to treat close times as equal.

Comment: Use no of records in both lists which is nearly equal time

Comment: @NithinMohan: So your desired result is an integer, the number of objects which have "equal" times? What if the first list contains objects with "equal" times, are they counted as well? So for example, list1 contains 10 records with same DateTime and list2 contains one matching object. Is the result 1 or 10?

Comment: Please also add required result for your given example.

Comment: So `P1` and `P2` are two different types that happen to have some properties with the same names and types (`Value` and `DateTime`)?

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Yes, the properties for the both lists are same. I will modify my question according to the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use looping through `p_one` while applying LINQ methods at each step to get all records from `p_two` "30 seconds away" from current `p_one` record.
Then you can store it in `List` of `Tuples` for example to have all info.

```
List<RESULTSET> summary = new List<RESULTSET>();
for (int i = 0; i < p_one.Count; i++)
    summary.AddRange(p_two.Where(p2 => Math.Abs((p2.DateTime - p_one[i].DateTime).TotalSeconds) <= 30).Select(p2 => new RESULTSET(){Value = p_one[i].Value + p2.Value, DateTime = p_one[i].DateTime }));
```

I used following classes:

```
public class P1 { public int Value; public DateTime DateTime; }
public class P2 { public int Value; public DateTime DateTime; }
public class RESULTSET { public int Value; public DateTime DateTime; }
```

NOTE, that they are identical and you could use `P1` class everywhere.

Comment: This is not I am expecting.I tested the method

Comment: @NithinMohan Try updated answer. Here `Tuple<DateTime, int>` represents class with two fields: one `int` and one `DateTime`. You can replace it with your own desired class.

Comment: I updated the question. The expected result is not met.

Comment: For your answer it will return 67 records, but my expected result contain maximum 8 no.s which is equal to the no.of records of smaller list p_one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for equality with a margin like so:

```
public static bool IsEqual(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, int marginSeconds = 30)
{
    return Math.Abs((d1 - d2).Seconds) < marginSeconds;
}
```

This should return `true` if d1 is "2018-09-18 10:15:00" d2 is "2018-09-18 10:15:10"

Then use this in your loop to equalize

Hope this helps.